# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core) on build

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

I am tring to implement Cloud Firestore into my note-taking program but I keep on getting this error twice:

> I/flutter ( 5328): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core) >I/flutter ( 5328): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

I have tried all the other remedies from the other similar pages, but none of them have worked. This is my main.dart:

```
//imports like material and cupertino above
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

// Import the firebase_core plugin
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: App(),));
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  // Set default `_initialized` and `_error` state to false
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = false;
  String error = '';

  // Define an async function to initialize FlutterFire
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        _initialized = true;
      });
    } catch(e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        error = e.toString();
        _error = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show error message if initialization failed
    if(_error) {
      print(error);
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                '${error}'
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );;
    }

    return NoteApp();
  }
}


class NoteApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const NoteApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NoteAppState createState() => _NoteAppState();
}

class _NoteAppState extends State<NoteApp> {
...
  }
```

And this is my pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:

  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: ^5.4.1
  cloud_firestore_web: ^2.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^2.5.1
  collection: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.6.0
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.0.1
```

and this is my build.gradle:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        }
        defaultConfig{
// add the following line
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how to solve this that is not like the other problems?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project with command, `flutter create myapp` and upgrade the version of gradle build tools to 3.5.0 as mentioned [here](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/3212).

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0
```

Answer (score -1):

I just create a new project and moved all my files to it then every thing work well for me, Maybe because I create my old project before upgrading my flutter(different flutter versions  old project and current flutter).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33717300)